# Running an progress indicator when loading multiple subscriptions

Tags: angular

Im still new to Angular but I wanted to show an loading screen with a % indicator so that users know how load it can take for that everything is loaded.

My example below works but its still buggy and I do think that it can be better.

I did run into the following issues

- it would be nice that I didnt needed a way to set a timer interval(its should count the correct interval based on the number of subscriptions that are  loading)
- at start it does not run the count but only once the first subscription has been loaded.

My code

```
<div *ngIf="!loaded" class="splash">
<div>
  <div class="loader"></div>
  <div class="progress">{{ progress }}%</div>
</div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="loaded" class="container">
  // content
</div>

export class PagesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public loaded: boolean = false;
  private subscription$!: Subscription;
  public progress: number = 0;
  private progressIncrement: number = 15;

  constructor(
    private toolService: ToolApiService,
    private toolSetService: ToolSetApiService,
    private orderApiService: OrderApiService,
    private stockRequestService: StockRequestService,
    private fastenerService: FastenerService,
    private usersService: UserService,
    private organisationMachineApiService: OrganizationMachineApiService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription$ = combineLatest([
      this.toolService.getAll().pipe(
        map(() => {
          this.progressTimer();
        }),
      ),
      this.toolSetService.getAll().pipe(
        map(() => {
          this.progressTimer();
        }),
      ),
      this.orderApiService.findAll().pipe(
        map(() => {
          this.progressTimer();
        }),
      ),
      this.stockRequestService.findAll().pipe(
        map(() => {
          this.progressTimer();
        }),
      ),
      this.usersService.getIvmUserList().pipe(
        map(() => {
          this.progressTimer();
        }),
      ),
      this.organisationMachineApiService.getAll().pipe(
        map(() => {
          this.progressTimer();
        }),
      ),
      this.fastenerService.findAll().pipe(
        map(() => {
          this.progressTimer();
        }),
      ),
    ]).subscribe(() => {
      this.progressTimer();
    });
  }

  progressTimer() {
    let i = 1;
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (i <= this.progressIncrement && this.progress < 100) {
        this.progress = this.progress + 1;
        i++;
      } else {
        clearInterval(timer);
        if (this.progress === 100) {
          this.loaded = true;
        }
      }
    }, 100);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription$.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your service-methods seem to fetch json-objects from the backend and it's hard to determine the download-progress in percent when it comes to json. The main problem is that with json you normally don't know the total-byte-size until the data is downloaded completely.

What I could offer you: An rxjs-based solution that increments the progress-bar by (100/numberOfRequests) percent, everytime a download completes. So in your example the steps would roughly look like: 0% => 14% => 28% => etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't track the actual remaining download time, especially not for json-payloads. On the one hand, you don't know the total number of bytes to be downloaded before the download starts. Also, the internet does not guarantee a constant download speed.

I have now built an rxjs-based progress tracker that increments the percentage progress by (100/number of requests) after each download of a JSON payload. Thanks to the use of Angular material, the transitions between the individual progress steps are also pretty smooth.

The **TS-Part** looks as follows:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { delay, forkJoin, Observable, scan, Subject, Subscription, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-simple-progress-bar',
  templateUrl: './simple-progress-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./simple-progress-bar.component.scss']
})

export class SimpleProgressBarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    private progressInPercentSubject = new Subject<number>();

    // Creates a mechanism to sum up all download-percentages:
    progressInPercent$ = this.progressInPercentSubject.pipe(
        scan((acc, curr) =>  acc + curr, 0),
        startWith(0)
    );

    isLoaded = false;
    subs = new Subscription();

    constructor(private dataSvc: DataService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // Wire up all http-request-observables:
        const httpRequests: Observable<unknown>[] = [this.dataSvc.getOrders(),
                                                     this.dataSvc.getArticles(),
                                                     this.dataSvc.getItems()];
        const numberOfRequests = httpRequests.length;
        const trackedHttpRequests = httpRequests.map(req => this.trackProgress(req, numberOfRequests));

        // Initialize progress-bar:
        this.progressInPercentSubject.next(0);

        // Execute observables and print out the data retrieved from backend:
        this.subs.add(
            forkJoin(trackedHttpRequests).pipe(
                delay(1000), // Allows the '100%' status to be displayed briefly before the content gets displayed
                tap(([ orders, articles, items ]) => {                  
                    console.log('Orders: ', orders);
                    console.log('Articles: ', articles);
                    console.log('Items: ', items);

                    this.isLoaded = true;
                })
            )                       
            .subscribe());
    }

    /* Tracks the progress of a single observable */
    trackProgress(apiRequest: Observable<unknown>, requestsTotal: number): Observable<unknown> {
        return apiRequest.pipe(
            tap(_ => this.progressInPercentSubject.next(100/requestsTotal))
        );
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subs.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Then the **HTML-Part**:
It was created with `mat-progress-bar` to enable a smooth transition between the progress-steps:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!isLoaded">
        
        <div class="progress-bar">
            <div class="progress-bar-text">
                {{ progressInPercent$ | async | number : '1.1-1' }} %
            </div>          
            <mat-progress-bar color="accent" mode="determinate" [value]="progressInPercent$ | async"></mat-progress-bar>
        </div>
    
</ng-container>


<ng-container *ngIf="isLoaded">

    <div class="page-content">
        LOADING COMPLETED
    </div>

</ng-container>
```

Comment: @user759235 : Sorry, I just found a bug in my code and had to correct the following:
1.) I added `startWith(0)` to the `progressInPercent$`-mechanism and I changed the html-part, so that `progressInPercent$` is no longer part of *ngIf, but rather assigned directly inside the `progress-bar-text` element.